# Blank final variables are used to create immutable objects

Tags: java, final

I know that blank variables are used to create immutable objects in java i.e. Objects whose member can't be changed 
How does the following lines of code work without any problem

```
import java.util.*;

class B
{
    int a;
}    
public class BlankFinal
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      final B b;
      b=new B();
      b.a=1;

      System.out.println(b.a);

      b.a=23;         // b object's a member is changed even though b is 
                      // blank final 

      System.out.println(b.a);

   }     
 }
```

Comment: If your bag is final, it means you can't swap it for a different bag. Doesn't mean you can't take stuff out of the bag or put new stuff in.

Comment: Nice analogy thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `b` is final only prevents you from assigning a new value to `b` (after its initial initialization). It doesn't prevent you from calling methods of `B` that mutate the state of the object referenced by `b`, or mutating the instance variables of the object referenced by `b` directly (i.e. `b.a = ...`).

Answer (score 2):

The reference to `B b` is final, and cannot be changed. When you try to change the value of the datafield `b.a`, it will allow you to do so because it does not change that reference.

Comment: Almost right, but `final int a` without initializing it in the constructor won't work.

Comment: But you can initialise it outside of a constructor (in BlankFinal), but reassignment wouldn't work.

Comment: True, but as it stands right now it would not compile.

Comment: my mistake, that's correct, edited the answer. Thanks!